# Como Configuro un boton de volver dependiendo de rol

Tags: botón

Tengo mi aplicación, entonces para no crear muchas ventanas para cada rol, solo cree una ventana para ese rol y le agregué los mismos botones a todos que ya había creado.

Pero entonces mi error es que si ingreso con un rol diferente al Admin, por ejemplo tengo uno de chef e ingreso al inventario y le doy volver al menú del chef no me envía a él si no que me redirige al menú del Admin. No se como arreglar eso.

A continuación está el código el botón volver al menú:

```
public void evento_jbVolver()
{    
    // MenuAdmin MA;
    // MA = new MenuAdmin(mp);
    setVisible(false);
    dispose();
    MC.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberías de crear todas las actividades de todos los roles y, dependiendo del tipo de rol que tenga, derivarlo a una u otra actividad con condicionales if o switch.